# how to update existing JSON file in java

Tags: java, json

This is my sample Json

```
 {
        "State": {
            "version": "1",
            "SName": "Test",
            "shippingDetails": {
                "Address1": "AP",
                "ZipCode": "1236"
            },
            "Directions": {
                "routes": [
                    {
                        "taxAmount": "0.0",
                        "Quantity": "5",
                        "bounds": {
                            "SerialVersion": [
                                {
                                    "text": "1.7 km",
                                    "value": "1729",
                                    "time": "02633"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": "1.9 km",
                                    "value": "1829",
                                    "time": "02353"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": "17 km",
                                    "value": "1059",
                                    "time": "02133"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to update SName, ZipCode,taxAmount,Quantity, and text[1] values
are there any way to do this. I am taking JSON in a file and update tags are taking into HashMap

Comment: If you have them in the `HashMap`, you can directly change the values and convert it back to `JSON`.

Comment: @HarshalParekh i am taking json in file and tags which need to be updated in hash map not entire json

Comment: To modify the JSON, you need to load the entire JSON.

Comment: @HarshalParekh  can you provide one example?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329607/8430155

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map)

Comment: @HarshalParekh your solution is good for simple json. but it wont work with nested json.

Comment: .put() is always for a *simple* JSON. If you need to update a nested JSON, you’ll have to .get() it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("Your_JSON_String");

JSONObject jsonObjectForState = jsonObject.getJSONObject(“State”);

jsonObjectForState.put("Sname", "New_Value_Here");
```

`put(...)` will replace the current value with new value. Similarly, you can update the other values. Once you are done, you can convert it back using:

```
jsonObject.toString();
```

And write it back to the file.

Comment: its not working and new tag is appending at outside of State{}

Comment: So that is from someone else who thinks the question might not help others in the future or the question quality is not upto the mark. In the future, please go through this before posting a question to avoid negative votes: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/